# How to pull a remote branch locally?

Tags: git, gitlab, branch

I created a project on Gitlab and cloned it on my computer. So I only have one branch (master) locally (`git branch` only shows `master`). A colleague created a new branch. So now there are 2 branches on Gitlab but not on my computer.

How do I do to have the branch created by my co-worker on my computer too so as `git branch` shows both `master` and  `new-branch` ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 19):

**First, update your remote-tracking branches** (local replicas of the remote branches, with which you can't interact in the same way you do with *your own* local branches). It's typically done with

```
git fetch
```

*(without any parameters,* `--all` *is implied)*

Your local repo will then know every new branch your coworker could have created since you last fetched (or pulled, since a pull does a fetch as a first step).

**Then you'll be able to create a local counterpart** for any of these remote branches with

```
git checkout <branchName>
```

Here, note that `<branchName>` is meant to be given without the `<remote>/` prefix, or else git will attempt to check out the so-named remote-tracking branch, which it can't, by design. At this point it will then resolve the branch ref to the commit which this remote-tracking branch points to, check this commit out directly, resulting in a detached HEAD state. (which is no big deal but can unsettle people starting to use git)

Answer (score 12):

Try:

```
git fetch
```

This will updates all branches and pull them locally.

Or:

```
git fetch remote_repo remote_branch:local_branch
```

If you're interested in one branch only, then:

```
git checkout local_branch
```

Comment: It's spelled `git` not `gît` :)

Comment: Very anecdotically, `gît` is not unsightly for people who happen to have walked through a french cemetary at least once ;-) Definitely not a *random* typo!

Comment: git fetch will not create or pull any remote branches locally if there are not already existing. A git pull is a "git fetch + git merge with exisiting"
At least with git release 1.8.3.1.
The question was related to a non-existing branch.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your remote is called `origin`
your friend's branch is called `Friend_Remote` and you want to name the branch locally as `Friend_Local`

Create a new branch and name is `Friend_Local`:

```
git checkout -b Friend_Local
```

Then pull the remote branch to your local one

```
git pull origin Friend_Remote
```